# Async API call handler inside event listener in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In React, I have a text field for searching students. I am listening to the typed query inside an **onChange()** event handler for the searchfield, where I am also making an API call to search for students, as shown in the code snippet

```
state = {
    searchResult: []
}

searchStudents = (event) => {
    if(!event.target.value) {
      this.setState({
        searchResult: []
      })
    } else {
      StudentAPI.search(event.target.value)
      .then(resp => {
        if (resp && resp.error === "empty query") {
          this.setState({
            searchResult: []
          })
        } else {
          this.setState({
            searchResult: resp
          })
        }
      }).catch(e => {
        this.setState({
          searchResult: []
        })
      });
    }
  }

...
<input className="search-input" onChange={this.searchStudents} />
```

Now everything is working fine. As I type a query then search results are populating in the state. As I delete or add text to query the result updates accordingly.
I want the search result to be blank if The problem is when I slowly remove the text from the search field, the search result in the state changes to empty. But when I quickly remove all the text from the search field, the state still has search results.

I know the problem here might be that after the **onChange** is complete on empty search field, there is still an API response pending, due to which the state updates.

**API Sample Responses:**

1. query: "Jhon"

```
[{
   "name" : "Jhon Doe",
   "school": "School of Accounting",
   "registration_number": "FA2020ACC8485"
},{
   "name" : "Jhon Oliver",
   "school": "School of Engineering",
   "registration_number": "FA2020ENG4526"
},
....
]
```

2. query: ""

```
{'error': "Please provide a query"}
```

**API Service**

```
export const search = (query) =>
  fetch(`${api}/search`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ query })
  }).then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => data.students)
```

How to handle this situation?

Comment: What does your API method look like?

Comment: I would like to see what `StudentAPI.search` looks like.